# Angular service call a child method in constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a way to call a child class method from an abstract service? When I do this, the `if` statement doesn't execute because `onInit` doesn't exist. I am not sure why it doesn't exist though. Maybe there is an "angular" way of doing this instead of triggering this on the init. Or maybe I just need to call the onInit manually in the component instead. Basically what I am doing is trying to get the initial application data from the server.

```
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class RootService {
  public constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    if(typeof this.onInit === 'function') {
      this.onInit()
    }
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class MyService extends RootService {
  public onInit() {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

```
@Component()
export MyComponent {
  public constructor(myService: MyService) {}
}
```

Comment: How can `RootService` know that `MyService` even exists? What are you trying to accomplish, perhaps there is another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services do not have lifecycle events. However, components [have lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) such as:

- ngOnChanges()
- ngOnInit()
- ngDoCheck()
- ...

So you can load data when your component is initialized. If yes, then just use `ngOnInit`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component()
export MyComponent  implements OnInit {
    yourData;

    public constructor(myService: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        myService.loadData()
            .subscribe(s=> yourData = s);
    }
}
```

[According to Angular docs:](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

> OnInit is a lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has
>   initialized all data-bound properties of a directive.

Comment: What I would like is to load data when the service is initialized. Maybe that isn't the right approach though...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Do you want to cache this data in service? What for do you want to load data when service initialized?

Comment: I have variables in the service that when the data loads it gets saved into the variables.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn then you can call the service from the component and save this data into variables of this services.

Comment: That is what I thought I might have to do. I was hoping I could get it to auto init the data when the constructor was called.

Comment: Yeah, you can call some your method of service in constructor of the service like that: `constructor() { this.sayHello(); }`, however, in my view, it is not great solution. The better solution is to call the desired method from the component as services should be really simple without any own logic. It is just my opinion.

Comment: It looks like what I would like it to use an `APP_INITIALIZER` provider within the module. to load this data.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the service to the providers of your component, it will be in your components scope then you can call onInit in your service as well.

But the downside of this is you can no longer share the same instance of the service among your components.

This will be valid if your service only serves one component.